# Placing elemenents with css?

Tags: css

I want to place image floated left, next to image, floated left one under another would be Authro, Date and Category, than, after this other elements will be floated on right side...
Like this...
https://i.imgur.com/tcKwalP.png

This is what I have so far...
https://jsfiddle.net/fbn9r3y4/

This is html...

```
<div class="entry-meta">

<span class="entry-image">
<a class="entry-image-a" href="">
<img src="image.jpg" height="48" width="48">
</a>
</span>

<span class="entry-author">
<a href="" title="" rel="author">Ester</a> 
</span>
<span class="entry-date">September 3, 2019</span>

<span class="entry-category-single">
<a href="">Music</a>
</span>

<span class="meta-right">

<span class="entry-views"><span class="view-count">998</span>  Views</span>

<span class="entry-like">
<span class="sl-wrapper">
<a href="" class="sl-button">
<span class="sl-count">500<em>Likes</em></span>
</a>

<span class="sl-loader"></span>
</span>
</span>     
</span>

</div>
```

This is css...

```
.entry-meta {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding: 10px 2px;
}

.entry-image {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.entry-author {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.entry-date {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    clear: left;
}

.entry-category-single {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    clear: left;
}

.meta-right {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    order: 2;
    float: right;
}


.entry-like {
    min-width: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

.entry-views {
    min-width: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a quick comment, you might want to consider switching the `<span>` to `<div>` since you're already changing the display property to block, starting out with a block element is a little more semantic.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I can do that, switch span to div. Either way works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed up your markup a little bit and added a wrapping `meta-left` around the content of the left side. I also simplified your CSS. There were several CSS properties that were invalid or not necessary.

```css
.entry-meta {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  padding: 10px 2px;
}

.entry-meta::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.meta-left {
  float: left;
}

.meta-right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.entry-image {
  float: left;
}

.meta-info {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.entry-like {
  min-width: 32px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.entry-views {
  min-width: 32px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-meta">
  <div class="meta-left">

    <div class="entry-image">
      <a class="entry-image-a" href="">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/48" height="48" width="48">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="meta-info">
      <div class="entry-author">
        <a href="#" title="" rel="author">Ester</a>
      </div>
      <div class="entry-date">September 3, 2019</div>

      <div class="entry-category-single">
        <a href="#">Music</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="meta-right">

    <div class="entry-views"><span class="view-count">998</span> Views</div>

    <div class="entry-like">
      <span class="sl-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="sl-button">
          <span class="sl-count">500<em> Likes</em></span>
      </a>

      <span class="sl-loader"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a version using `display: flex` that's even simpler. Same markup.

```css
.entry-meta {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.meta-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.meta-info {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-meta">
  <div class="meta-left">

    <div class="entry-image">
      <a class="entry-image-a" href="">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/48" height="48" width="48">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="meta-info">
      <div class="entry-author">
        <a href="#" title="" rel="author">Ester</a>
      </div>
      <div class="entry-date">September 3, 2019</div>

      <div class="entry-category-single">
        <a href="#">Music</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="meta-right">

    <div class="entry-views"><span class="view-count">998</span> Views</div>

    <div class="entry-like">
      <span class="sl-wrapper">
        <a href="" class="sl-button">
          <span class="sl-count">500<em> Likes</em></span>
      </a>

      <span class="sl-loader"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esteros. Please check this link
    https://codepen.io/juricon/pen/QWLOZea

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-meta">

<span class="entry-image">
<a class="entry-image-a" href="">
<img src="image.jpg" height="48" width="48">
</a>
</span>

<ul class="left-float-list">
    <ol>
      <a href="" title="" rel="author">
        Ester
      </a>
   </ol>
    <ol>
      September 3, 2019
    </ol>
    <ol>
      <a href="">
        Music
      </a>
   </ol>
</ul>

<ul class="right-float-list">
  <li class="items-reverse">
    <span class="entry-views">
    <!--do not miss nesting rules <tag><tag1></tag1</tag>  -->
      998
    </span>     
    <span class="view-count">     
      Views
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="entry-like">
      <span class="sl-wrapper"> <!--do not miss nesting rules <tag><tag1></tag1</tag>  Also, you don't have in CSS classes like .sl-wrapper .sl-button, .sl-count, sl-loader -->
         <a href="" class="sl-button">
            <span class="sl-count">
                500<em>Likes</em>
            </span>
      <!-- it is a bad idea to use <em> with not cursive text in one <span>. Use CSS to  style your text -->
        </a>

        <span class="sl-loader">
        </span>
      </span>
   </span> 

  </li>
  <li>
    Whatever
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
*{ /*clear styles*/
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
   /*clear styles*/
}

.entry-meta {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding: 10px 2px;
}

.entry-image{
    float: left;
}
.left-float-list{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    list-style:none;
    background: green;
    margin-left:.4em;
}


.right-float-list{
    float: right;
    list-style:none;
    background: red;
    margin-right:1em;
}

.entry-views, .entry-like {
    min-width: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Esteros,  here you will find a great web development free course https://www.freecodecamp.org/ and 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp. 
It will help you a lot. Good luck!

P.S.: Use Flexbox instead of "float" and you won't regret.